# Is there a maximum file size applied to uploads in to Tridion?

Tags: cme

If a user uploads a binary item to a multimedia schema in Tridion is there a limit on the size of the file that may be selected?

Comment: As an implementation choice, some event system code can limit upload size and even give authors feedback. See [an "semantic" multimedia example](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/UsingSemanticMultimediaSchemas) from @DominicCronin. I'm also a fan of basic Custom URLs and Custom Pages to guide authors on what's reasonable for a given content type, since it depends on the setup as Nuno explains.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some limits...

- WebDav limits uploads (by default) to 4 MB (see the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_E1E4BB75BEB84404B4EFAFC6B8A22D15) for details on how to change this).
- IIS may block by default uploads of files over 30MB (not sure if this still applies, can't find references in the documentation).
- HTTPUpload will (again, by default) limit upload sizes to 10MB for publishing packages.

All these values can be modified, Tridion itself doesn't have a "hard" limit to file sizes, but you should know that large files have an impact on the underlying infrastructure (network, deployers, databases).

Comment: IIS limits are still relevant. It has been listed in the "Known issues" section for the CME for several releases (http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/CME_concept_242A17EC385644C8A77F2C976576492C)